# Filter not working on repeatable field type

Tags: development, module, joomla-3.4

I have a repeatable field in my custom module, and a `textarea` field inside it.

```
<field name="repeatable_field"
    type="Repeatable"
    icon="list"
    label="My Repeatable field">
    <fieldset hidden="true" name="repeatable_field_modal" repeat="true">
        <field name="text_area"
            label="Text"
            size="30"
            type="textarea"
            filter="raw" />
    </fieldset>
</field>
```

Even if I add `filter="raw"` to the field declaration, any HTML code removed from my `textarea` field.

How can I apply a filter to fields inside a Repeatable element?

Answer (score 3):

In order to apply a filter to a field inside a Repeatable field, the filter has to be applied to the *repeatable element itself*, not to fields inside.

This works:

```
<field name="repeatable_field"
    type="Repeatable"
    icon="list"
    label="My Repeatable field"
    filter="raw">
    <fieldset hidden="true" name="repeatable_field_modal" repeat="true">
        <field name="text_area"
            label="Text"
            size="30"
            type="textarea" />
    </fieldset>
</field>
```